No matching distribution found for torch==1.9.0+cu102
I am trying to use pixray on macOS
but it looks like the dependencies mentioned in the requirements.txt aren't updated. These are the steps I followed:

created a pyenv virtual env:
Python 3.8.10

Cloned the repo:
git clone https://github.com/pixray/pixray.git --recursive

cd pixray

pip install -r requirements.txt


but now I get this:
  Running command git clone -q https://github.com/pixray/aphantasia /private/var/folders/mn/tn1xcsr133z5ql6x9tctkd040000gr/T/pip-req-build-pux3s766
  WARNING: Did not find branch or tag '7e6b3bb', assuming revision or ref.
  Running command git checkout -q 7e6b3bb
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement torch==1.9.0+cu102 (from versions: 1.8.1, 1.9.0, 1.9.1, 1.10.0, 1.10.1, 1.10.2, 1.11.0, 1.12.0, 1.12.1, 1.13.0, 1.13.1, 2.0.0, 2.0.1, 2.1.0, 2.1.1, 2.1.2, 2.2.0, 2.2.1, 2.2.2)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for torch==1.9.0+cu102


requirements.txt
### THIS IS THE SAME AS REQUIREMENTS.TXT but with a different version of cuda (102) for cog

# these are minimal requirements for just the VQGAN drawer

-f https://download.pytorch.org/whl/torch_stable.html
torch==1.9.0+cu102
torchvision==0.10.0+cu102
torchtext==0.10.0

numpy==1.19.4
tqdm==4.49.0
matplotlib==3.3.4
braceexpand==0.1.7
colorthief==0.2.1
einops==0.3.2
imageio==2.9.0
ipython==7.28.0
kornia==0.6.2
omegaconf==2.1.1
Pillow==8.3.2
PyYAML==5.4.1
scikit_learn==1.0
scikit-image==0.18.3
torch_optimizer==0.1.0
torch-tools==0.1.5

# can use CompVis/taming-transformers when https://github.com/CompVis/taming-transformers/pull/81 is merged
git+https://github.com/bfirsh/taming-transformers.git@7a6e64ee
git+https://github.com/openai/CLIP
git+https://github.com/pvigier/perlin-numpy@6f077f8

# diffvg: these are minimal requirements for just the pixeldraw / linedraw etc drawers

# DO THIS: "git clone https://github.com/pixray/diffvg && cd diffvg && git submodule update --init --recursive && CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH=$(pyenv prefix) DIFFVG_CUDA=1 python setup.py install"
cmake==3.21.3
cssutils==2.3.0
svgpathtools==1.4.2


# fft: these are IN ADDITION to the core requirements_vqgan.txt

lpips
sentence_transformers
opencv-python
PyWavelets==1.1.1
git+https://github.com/fbcotter/pytorch_wavelets

# main aphantasia library
git+https://github.com/pixray/aphantasia@7e6b3bb

# slip
timm

# resmem loss
resmem

where should i make a change? Should I update the python version or the library version inside the requirements.txt?

Today, I was struggling to install it as well. It seems that torch team is moving the old packages. Try: pip install torch==1.9.0 -f https://download.pytorch.org/whl/torch_stable.html where this download link seems to have the most packages and by removing the cuda dependency, you will see if the problem comes from finding an old version of torch. Check if the version you want is also available for your version of python - see https://stackoverflow.com/a/75023291/9815708

This is due to a compatibility issue between PyTorch and Python, the "Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement" refers to the currently installed Python version not being compatible (because too recent) with PyTorch version 1.9.0. PyTorch releases try to keep up with newer Python versions, but they cannot maintain older PyTorch versions to work with newly released Python versions. It turns out, that back when 1.9.0 was released, PyTorch was not providing support for Python 3.8 (probably because it was not released yet!).
So you have two options:

either downgrade Python to something compatible with PyTorch 1.9.0. According to the author of the pixray repository you linked, Python 3.7 should be working.
Or you can upgrade the PyTorch version: with your current Python 3.8, you can safely install the latest PyTorch 2.2.2. In that case, you risk breaking other dependencies in the installation.

I recommend going with the first option as it is the safest if you are just trying to run their code.

I also tried Python 3.7 (pyenv virtual env) but had the same error. Were you able to reproduce it?

Oh I remember now, you're running on a MAC, correct?

yes it's a macos

That's why, you don't have CUDA, according to the installation page of PyTorch, you should use: pip install torch==1.9.0 torchvision==0.10.0 torchaudio==0.9.0 

If you're on an Intel Mac, you need to install cuda drivers yourself. I would first try to use Python 3.10 (or later) and install the latest versions of all the requirements, rather than first trying to downgrade Python.

I've followed your steps and was able to regenerate the error -

Now to remove the error, I tried installing the required pytorch and cuda version from the links given on the official website -
[https://pytorch.org/get-started/previous-versions/]
for my windows system the command will be -
pip install torch==1.9.0+cu102 torchvision==0.10.0+cu102 torchaudio==0.9.0 -f https://download.pytorch.org/whl/torch_stable.html

Results -
(pixray-env) PS C:\Users\...\Desktop\VS01\..\test> python --version   
Python 3.8.10                                                                         
(pixray-env) PS C:\Users\..\Desktop\VS01\..\test> pip install torch==1.9.0+cu102 torchvision==0.10.0+cu102 torchaudio==0.9.0 -f https://download.pytorch.org/whl/torch_stable.html
Looking in links: https://download.pytorch.org/whl/torch_stable.html
Collecting torch==1.9.0+cu102
  Downloading https://download.pytorch.org/whl/cu102/torch-1.9.0%2Bcu102-cp38-cp38-win_amd64.whl (1440.4 MB)
     ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 1.4/1.4 GB 3.0 MB/s eta 0:00:00
Collecting torchvision==0.10.0+cu102

Visit the link and find the suitable command by scrolling down and finding your requirement.
Also, sometimes you need to check if your system is using the correct python version or not, use the command python --version once before running the pytorch installation
